# Sidebar wrapper not expanding with page-content-wrapper

Tags: html, css

Struggling to figure this one out, any help is appreciated.

I've a main `#wrapper` div that wraps around the whole document. Then we have a `#sidebar-wrapper` for the navigation and a `#page-content-wrapper` for the content. The problem is that when the content expands the sidebar-wrapper doesn't. I know they are both absolutely positioned, I've tried relative positioning and that didn't work either.

The sidebar-wrapper div should expand down (height) to accompany the growth of the page-content-wrapper div.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here's the fiddle: [wrapper fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnp9fvpw/7/)

Found the SOLUTION: overflow-x on the page-content-wrapper should be set to hidden and that made the sidebar-wrapper expand to 100% of the document size.

Comment: Voting a question down for no reason is really helpful too... thanks. At least if you vote down say why you did so as I'm new here and trying to learn the ropes. Guess my question is too dumb for here.

Comment: Which direction are you wanting to expand? The question suggests the width but your fiddle indicates the height? Also looking at your fiddle you are using fixed units (px) not relative units (%). Fixed units won't naturally expand without javascript intervention or css media queries being defined

Comment: It should expand in height to match the page-content-wrapper div

Comment: Totally lucked the solution! The #page-content-wrapper overflow-x: attribute should be set to hidden, that made the sidebar expand in height to 100% of the document size. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position relative for outer wrapper like this:

```
#wrapper.toggled 
{
  padding-left: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. As it turns out the solution was in the page-content-wrapper overflow-x that somehow was affecting the other div. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: but I used this in your fiddle and it worked perfect!

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try it myself too. Thank you again Rohit.

Comment: Just tried it there and it didn't work for me I'm afraid. Neither in the fiddle nor in the actual code.